# Opencv Ptr class. Pointer object is deleted after function called

Tags: c++, opencv, abstract-class, smart-pointers

I want to make a wrapper over the opencv's FaceRecognizer class. I called it Identifier and here's the code

header

```
class Identifier
{
public:
Identifier();
Identifier(const std::string& filename);
Identifier(const TrainData& trainData);

~Identifier();

void train(const TrainData& trainData);

private:

cv::Ptr<cv::FaceRecognizer> _model;
};
```

CPP

```
#include "Identifier.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

Identifier::Identifier()
{
cout << "default constructor\n";
if(_model.empty())
    cout << "model has not been created\n";
}

Identifier::Identifier(const string& filename)
{
Identifier();

TrainData td;
td.load(filename);

if(_model.empty())
    cout << "constructor model is empty\n";

train(td);
}

Identifier::~Identifier()
{
_model.delete_obj();
}

Identifier::Identifier(const TrainData& trainData)
{
Identifier();

train(trainData);
 }

 void Identifier::train(const TrainData& trainData)
 {
cout << "train enter\n";
if(_model.empty())
    cout << "model is empty\n";

vector<cv::Mat> images;
vector<int> labels;

for(int i = 0; i < trainData.size(); ++i)
{
    Person curPerson = trainData[i];

    vector<string> curPersonImages = curPerson.getImages();

    int j = 0;

    for(auto imagePath: curPersonImages)
    {
        cv::Mat mat = cv::imread(imagePath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        images.push_back(mat);
        labels.push_back(curPerson.getId());
    }
}

cout << "here\n" 
        << images.size() << " - " << labels.size();

try
{
    _model->train(images, labels);
} catch(cv::Exception& e)
{
    cout << e.msg;
} catch(...)
{
    cout << "something goes wrong\n";
}
cout << "here 1\n";
 }
```

I have a problem with cv::Ptr, as I understand it is a some kind of smart pointer, but there is a problem, once I call cv::createLBPHFaceRecognizer(); in constructor, the pointer 
is released in the next function and my program is crashed, because object _model is empty. Does anyone can help me. How can I initialize _model once in constructor and then use it in other places?

I use opencv v2.4.9, MinGW as compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to call the empty constructor before a parameterized one, you would have to do it this way:

```
Identifier::Identifier()
   : model_( cv::createLBPHFaceRecognizer() )
{
}

Identifier::Identifier(const string& filename)
   : Identifier()
{
...
}
```

---

your Identifier(); call above makes a *local* copy , and deletes it

Comment: thank you very very much! I spend the whole morning trying to fix that problem! I mixed it up with Java way, where you can call constructor within other constructor as this(params ...);